# R: Loop to filter dataframe and print mean of column of filtered data into new dataframe

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, mean, repeat

I have this dataframe called `PlantGroNoT.RCP2.first.0` (randomly sampled it with dput()).

```
structure(list(Year = c(2040L, 2068L, 2096L, 2049L, 2072L, 2042L, 
2087L, 2047L, 2076L, 2075L, 2052L, 2054L, 2034L, 2060L, 2041L, 
2031L, 2067L, 2080L, 2055L, 2067L, 2095L, 2097L, 2097L, 2077L, 
2057L, 2038L, 2052L, 2095L, 2043L, 2075L), DOY = c(78L, 13L, 
20L, 364L, 23L, 14L, 352L, 72L, 54L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 53L, 43L, 63L, 
26L, 21L, 30L, 360L, 22L, 46L, 62L, 355L, 4L, 61L, 355L, 75L, 
51L, 46L, 39L), DAP = c(93L, 28L, 35L, 14L, 38L, 29L, 2L, 87L, 
69L, 17L, 16L, 20L, 68L, 58L, 79L, 41L, 36L, 45L, 10L, 37L, 61L, 
78L, 5L, 20L, 77L, 5L, 90L, 66L, 61L, 54L), NSTD = c(0.244, 0, 
0.023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.547, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.148, 0, 0, 0.001, 
0, 0, 0.186, 0.443, 0, 0, 0.278, 0, 0.403, 0.16, 0.085, 0.069
), RCP = c("2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "8", "4", "8", "4", 
"4", "4", "8", "4", "4", "2", "8", "8", "8", "4", "8", "2", "4", 
"8", "4", "8", "4", "4", "8", "2")), row.names = c(5634575L, 
1218676L, 788139L, 7051284L, 6262001L, 1122307L, 3560772L, 3925983L, 
2584130L, 3401700L, 1217186L, 1455727L, 2993448L, 597952L, 5893799L, 
6696664L, 2345802L, 3105731L, 6347255L, 5005396L, 3330449L, 780805L, 
2522272L, 3668256L, 2099405L, 818891L, 1123257L, 5237622L, 1259779L, 
1623133L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to filter it by `RCP`, `DAP`and `Year`. From the result of this filter, I would like to take the mean of`NSTD`and print it into the `NSTDmean` column of the dataframe `HO1_2020_RCP2_stress`

`DAP` ranges from 0 to 114, so in the first cell of `HO1_2020_RCP2_stress$WSPDmean` I would like to have the NSTDmean for `DAP`==0, in the second cell the mean for `DAP`==1, etc.

I created this loop to do the job.

```
i = -1
  repeat{
    i= i+1
    PlantGroNoT.RCP2.first.0 <- filter(PlantGroNoT_1, RCP==2 & DAP==i & Year<=2060)
    H01_2020_RCP2_stress$NSTDmean <- mean(PlantGroNoT.RCP2.first.0$NSTD, na.rm=TRUE)
    if (i>114)
      break
  }
```

The filter and mean calculation itself work.

However, the loop does not return the `NSTDmean` correctly in the `HO1_2020_RCP2_stress$WSPDmean` column. It always prints the value for the last i (i.e. here DAS==114) for the whole `NSTDmean` column.

Comment: hm, `subset(PlantGroNoT_1, RCP==2 & Year<2060)` has only two observations. Eventually for the original dataframe `with(PlantGroNoT_1, tapply(NSTD, DAP, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))` ?

Comment: thanks! It does work: ```subset <- subset(PlantGroNoT_1, RCP==2 & Year<=2060)
     with <- with(subset, tapply(NSTD, DAP, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))
     H01_2020_RCP2_stress$NSTDmean <- with```

Comment: normally it is not a good idea to use names of R-functions for userdefined objects.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't misunderstand what you want to do but I think using `group_by` is a valid approach:

```r
df %>%
  filter(RCP == 2 & Year <= 2060) %>% # These are the only conditions and they are fixed
  group_by(DAP) %>%
  summarise(NTSDT = mean(NSTD,na.rm =TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(DAP)
```

This will filter the data frame to only rows with RCP == 2 and Year <= 2060. Then it will summarise the mean of NSTD for all DAP values.

Should you need this result to be appended to the original data frame you could simply join it or use `mutate` instead of summarize.

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I want to do! I was struggling with the other `dplyr` commands. thanks!!